# getting a recursive count of complete directory structure

Tags: powershell

**How do we get a total count instead of 1 per folder?**

The following will iterate all folders in `$path` and produce something that looks like this:

[image]

`[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($path,'*.*','AllDirectories').Count`

**How do we get a total count instead of 1 per folder?**

Comment: `([System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($path,'*.*','AllDirectories') | Measure).Count`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `*` rather than `*.*`?

Comment: You could also just use `([System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories($path,'*','AllDirectories').Count` if you only care about this particular value.

Answer (score 0):

It is considered a good practice to use PowerShell cmdlets and not .Net object methods when possible. To get all folders you can use `Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Directory -Recurse`. Then you can wrap it in parenthesis and get Count property.

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Directory -Recurse).Count
```

If you wanted to use pipeline, the solution is

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Directory -Recurse | Measure-Object | Select -ExpandProperty Count
```